# How best to display formatted properties between web api and clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am converting a MVC 5 ecommerce project to consume WEB API services instead so as to develop a mobile app for it too. I need advice on how best to handle the prices of products.
In the current mvc app, the DisplayFormat attribute is working very fine.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, NullDisplayText = "-")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

The above displays the currency as expected (e.g. $200.29) but this does not seem to work in web api. It returns just the price digit in decimal. All the business logic now lives in the api.
NOW MY QUESTION: Is there a way to send this currency in its formatted type (i.e. displays as currency, e.g. $200.29) from the api directly so I don't have to handle formatting in all the clients that'll use the api such as mobile and web?
Or
I have to handle the formatting in all the clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a converter and attach as attribute so during deserialization, the data is returned as per format defined in Converter.

For example, following class represents converting decimal to currency format

```
internal class CurrencyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(decimal?));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Decimal? d = value as decimal?;
        JToken.FromObject(string.Format("{0:C}", d.GetValueOrDefault())).WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Now the above converter can be applied to property

```
public class Order
{
    public string Item {get; set;}
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CurrencyConverter))]
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

With above when response is returned by WebApi, the property price would be the currency format like shown below

```
{"Item":"Some Item","Price":"$2.34"}
```

You can refer to this dotnet fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5FTDz